# R Tool for Visual Studio - error: System.ArgumentException: The package does not have a ProvideToolWindowAttribute

Tags: r, visual-studio

I just installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 (community edition) with R Tool (on Win 7 Enterprise).

R seems to be working fine (I can create variables and plot), but 'R Interactive' window shows the following error message:

```
An exception was encountered while constructing the content of this frame.  This information is also logged in "C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_305216d4\ActivityLog.xml".

    Exception details:
    System.ArgumentException: The package does not have a ProvideToolWindowAttribute for tool window c2582843-58c9-4fe7-b4bd-864c17ad7ce2
    Parameter name: toolWindowType
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.ThrowNoMatchingToolWindowAttribute(Object toolWindowType, String paramName)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetToolWindowAttribute(Guid toolWindowType)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Guid& toolWindowType, Int32 id)
       at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()
```

So I cannot output results to console. Does anybody know how to fix it?

**Update:**

Here is log file (C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_305216d4\ActivityLog.xml)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/frpncfjzl1gwqpy/ActivityLog.xml?dl=0

**Another update**

I cross-posted on github https://github.com/Microsoft/RTVS/issues/4302 but so far no response.

Comment: Can you also add the content of `"C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_305216d4\ActivityLog.xml"`

Comment: @Hackerman, good question, just added a link to log file.

Answer (score 0):

A needed prereq is an R interpreter: CRAN-R or Microsoft R Open.
install the R Open interpreter and the R interactive will work.

https://mran.microsoft.com/download

Comment: Thank you for your reply. R is working just fine in MS Visual Studio, interactive window is missing. Github has some interesting suggestions.